# Nao 6 QiChat: Check user Input for specific word and answer accordingly

Tags: robotics, nao-robot, naos-project

The Plan:
I want Nao to ask a quiz-question to the user.
If the answer of the user contains a specifix word (in this case SME), i want him to say 'Correct'.
If the answer doesn't contain SME, he should say 'Wrong'.

My Question:
How can i check the user-answer for a specific word and answer accordingly.

```
topic: ~EnglishQuiz()
language: enu

u:([Question Quiz Quizquestion]) ^gotoRandom(quiz)

proposal:  %quiz What's the acronym of small-medium-sized enterprise?
u1:(SME) Correct, S M E stands for Small-Medium-Sized-Enterprise
u2:(#Here i need to check that the user said something else than SME) Wrong, it is S M E.
```

I tried different solutions from the documentation and cheat-sheet, but none worked for me.
[http://www.bx.psu.edu/~thanh/naoqi/naoqi/audio/dialog/aldialog_syntax_cheat_sheet.html](http://www.bx.psu.edu/%7Ethanh/naoqi/naoqi/audio/dialog/aldialog_syntax_cheat_sheet.html)
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/interaction/dialog/dialog-syntax_full.html#conditions

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: It's just a single `*` but the order matters, so it has to be under the preferred answer.

```
topic: ~EnglishQuiz()
language: enu

u:([Question Quiz Quizquestion]) ^gotoRandom(quiz)

proposal:  %quiz What's the acronym of small-medium-sized enterprise?
u1:(SME) Correct, S M E stands for Small-Medium-Sized-Enterprise
u2:(*) Wrong, it is S M E.
```